# Android ViewPager2 Prepare Fragments in Advance or Not

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-jetpack, android-viewpager2

Just curious about the **Performance** difference between these 2 approaches:

**Approach 1: Directly return new `Fragment` object for each position**

```
class ProductAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    override fun getItemCount() = 5

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = ProductPageFragment()    //here
}
```

**Approach 2: Prepare `Fragments` in advance and return by position**

```
class ProductAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    private val fragments = mutableListOf<ProductPageFragment>()

    init {
        repeat(5) { fragments.add(ProductPageFragment()) }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = 5

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = fragments[position]    //here
}
```

Comment: Approach #2 is fundamentally broken and will cause crashes

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference will depend on the Fragment and what it does where, but there usually little difference because

> When a fragment is instantiated, it begins in the INITIALIZED state. For a fragment to transition through the rest of its lifecycle, it must be added to a FragmentManager. The FragmentManager is responsible for determining what state its fragment should be in and then moving them into that state.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

Most fragments design do most of their work at higher lifecycle states e.g. at `CREATED`, therefore there will be little difference in performance as the lifecycle management by viewpager2 will be the same for each approach.